# Java: Split array by value

Tags: java

I'm trying to split an array into subarrays by value. For example (with the `main` function delaration and class name removed):

```java
int[] arr = {1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1};
for (int i : splitByVal(arr)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I already have one way to do this:

```java
public int[][] splitByVal(arr) {
    int prevItem = arr[0];
    ArrayList<Integer[]> chunks = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    ArrayList<Integer> currentChunk = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (i == prevItem) {
            currentChunk.add(i);
        }
        else {
            chunks.add((Integer[]) currentChunk.toArray());
            currentChunk.clear();
        }
        prevItem = i;
    }
    return chunks.toArray()
}
```

What I want to know is: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what is `slope`? if current element is not the same as `prevItem` then `prevItem = i;`. and you should put `.add(i)` outside of `if-else` block

Comment: @mangusta Sorry, I was reading something else while writing this question. `slope` is supposed to be `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was correctly mentioned in the comment you haven't provided definition of the `slope` in your code. So it's not completely clear what your code is doing.

However, this is just one of the possible ways to do it if I understood you correctly:

```
public int[][] splitByValue(final int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int number : arr) {
        map.put(number, map.getOrDefault(number, 0) + 1);
    }
    int[][] result = new int[map.keySet().size()][];
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
        result[i] = new int[map.get(key)];
        for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
            result[i][j] = key;
        }
        i++;
    }        
    return result;
}
```

The assumption here is that you are only dealing with array of integers.